# Get Value of PHP Array from Google Elevation API

Tags: php, json, google-elevation-api

I am developing a system to get values from gGoogle Api Elevation with PHP. I have it working and when I get the value it returns as String in this format:

```
{ "results" : [ { "elevation" : 914.033935546875, "location" : { "lat" : -25.4499861, "lng" : -49.2339611 }, "resolution" : 152.7032318115234 } ], "status" : "OK" }
```

I want to get the value of the elevation in this result, can you help me to do this? thanks you.

Comment: You probably have to parse the string as a JSON document.

Comment: yeas i did, it becomes an array with this format: Array ( [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [elevation] => 914.03393554688 [location] => Array ( [lat] => -25.4499861 [lng] => -49.2339611 ) [resolution] => 152.70323181152 ) ) [status] => OK )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is in [JSON](https://json.org/) format.

You can use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it to a PHP array.

```php
$json_string = <<<JSON
{
  "results": [
    {
      "elevation": 914.033935546875,
      "location": {
        "lat": -25.4499861,
        "lng": -49.2339611
      },
      "resolution": 152.7032318115234
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
JSON;

$array = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
echo $array['results'][0]['elevation'];
```

Output:

```
914.03393554688
```

Comment: hello, i tried this solution, but it gives me an error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: if i add true in the json_decode: $result = json_decode($response, true);
        echo $result[0]['elevation']; it gives me this error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ...

Comment: Hi Gouveia, I will be at my desk soon and will write a more complete (and correct) answer. :)

Comment: when i use the funcion json_decode, it becomes an array in thsi format:                 Array ( [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [elevation] => 914.03393554688 [location] => Array ( [lat] => -25.4499861 [lng] => -49.2339611 ) [resolution] => 152.70323181152 ) ) [status] => OK )

Comment: your answer  worked! thanks you very much for your atention.